# Deploying a WCF Web Service inside a TFS Build

Tags: wcf, iis, tfs

I have a number of WCF web services that I am trying to deploy to a directory structure on a TFS Build.  The project structure looks something like this:

```
Services Directory (svc.sln)
- Project1 (project1.csproj)
- Project2 (project2.csproj)
- Project3 (project3.csproj)
- ServicesProject
  - Project1
    - Project1.svc
  - Project2
    - Project2.svc
  - Project3
    - Project3.svc
  - bin
    - Project1.dll
    - Project2.dll
    - Project3.dll
```

So, In order to deploy this, on my desktop, I simply load ServicesProject.csproj, publish, select a publish profile and it will happily publish to a single directory (ready to be copied across to IIS).

I then tried to add this to a TFS build, using the arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyPublishProfile
```

I got an error, saying that:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (182): Could not copy the file "bin\Project1.dll" because it was not found.
```

I had a look in the agent build directory and, sure enough, there was only one dll in there (ServicesProject.dll).  I then changed the build to build svc.sln, but I still get the same error.  I checked the build order for the sln file, and it does have ServicesProject last, however, the log file indicates that it gets built second.

I've provided so much detail, in case the answer to this lies in the approach I'm taking, rather than the specifics of what I'm actually doing.

My question is: am I doing this correctly and, if so, why is the sln file being build in the wrong order.  Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that any deployment from TF Build is the wrong way to achieve this. You should instead look to output the website, which is automatic, and deploy it using Release Management.

http://nakedalm.com/create-release-management-pipeline-professional-developers/

RM is built into TFS, all though you need to install it separately, and lets you create a deployment using PowerShell. It's very easy to do deployment and configuration of your website, and in the post you can see switching variables is also trivial.

Much easyer than trying to shoehorn deployment into a build tool.

Comment: Thanks for this - I didn't know about RM.  Having said that, it doesn't resolve my issue.  Whether or not it's deploying in the correct way, the build is still failing (even if I take out the MSBuild arguments).

Comment: Do you have dll's in the bin folder checked in? Coz if you do you need to delete them from source...

Comment: No the binaries are not source controlled

Comment: Do you have any references that are directly to DLL's in the Bin folder rather than project references?

Comment: Thanks for this Martin - turns out that was it.  I'm in the process of installing RM now... although I notice it's only available with a Premium License.